# My Code Always outputs a 0 I not know what is wrong

Tags: c#

I am trying to find the number of 3 digit numbers that has 2 numbers that are the factors of the third. So for example, 248 would be valid since 2 * 4 = 8 and 933 would also be valid since 3 * 3 = 9.

```
using System;

class Program
{
  public static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
    int Total = 0;
    for (int i = 100; i < 1000; i++)
    {
      string I = Convert.ToString(i);
      Console.WriteLine(I[2]+" "+I[1]+" "+I[0]+" "+I);
      if (I[2] == I[1] * I[0] || I[1] == I[0] * I[2] || I[0] == I[2] * I[1])
      {
        Console.WriteLine("true");
        Total++;
      }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("the total is");
    Console.WriteLine(Total);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to multiply numbers, not characters. `I[2]` is a character (and so are `I[0]` and `I[1]`)

Comment: Thanks so do I convert them to int and than multiply them

Comment: Now is the best time to start learning how to use a debugger.  See [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour).

Comment: Yea i have VS at home but im using a Chromebook at school using an online compiler

Comment: Is `913` valid?  because `1` and `3` are both _factors of 9_.  (Perhaps your problem is worded incorrectly.)

Comment: no its not i mean like 2 numbers that when multiplied together it is the other

Comment: As an aside, I'd strongly advise you to learn about .NET naming conventions and start applying them before you get into bad habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access a string by index, you get a `char` and not an int. To get an int out of a char, you have to parse it back:

```
var a = int.Parse(I[0].ToString());
var b = int.Parse(I[1].ToString());
var c = int.Parse(I[2].ToString());
```

Then you can do your multiplication like `a == b * c` and so on

Comment: tysm it works now